# Which way does the F-16 cannon rotate, and why in that direction?

Tags: aerodynamics, f-16

The F16 cannon is turning when fire the bullets. What is the direction when looking from the front of the aircraft towards behind?

Comment: https://www.f-16.net/f-16_armament_article5.html

Comment: "Why is it not in the other direction?"  Well, you gotta pick one or the other, right?!  ;)

Comment: If it was turning the other way, it would be sucking in bullets.

Comment: Sorry, I only know the direction when looking from the rear of the aircraft towards forward.

Comment: On a more serious note, the direction of rotation of the barrell assembly is most probably chosen such, that it will enhance the stability os the ammunition trajectory,  possibly enhancing the efficiency of the weapon in the same time (I'm guessing very little, but it is possible though). I do not know which way this would be, the same or opposite to the rotation of the ammunition itself.

Comment: The article Ron linked says the rotation is ccv viewed from behind the gun.

Comment: Probably in the same direction as the rifling in the barrels. Why design the weapon to reduce the stabilizing effect of the rifling (by rotating the barrels opposite the rifling ), when you could just as easily increase it by rotating the barrels in the same direction? and the rpm of the M-61 cannon at high rate is 1000 rpm, which is significant. The M61 barrels uses progressive right hand parabolic 10 inch twist with a muzzle velocity of 3200+ fps.  Without rotating the barrels,  that equates to the bullet leaving the barrel at about 4000 rpm. Reducing that by 1000 rpm would be significant.

Comment: Charles Bretana, very good explanation

Comment: As it turns out per WPNSguy's answer, and Charles' comment, the barrell assembly and the bullet are "counter rotating". WPNSguy's reasoning about this is plausible. There is in fact, such a thing as "overstabilized bullets" where the bullet spins too fast, and will not conform to gradual change in speed and trajectory. This may have been taken into account in gun rifling design, probably has been.

Comment: I need to revise my comment... Actually, although this seems like a very large number, leaving the barrel, the bullet is spinning at about 240,000 rpm.  The 4000 value I incorrectly mentioned above would actually be 4000 revolutions per *second*, since it is based on muzzle velocity of 3200 fp*s*. So adding or reducing the rpm by only 1000 would not be that significant. It still seems like it would make sense to increase rpm rather than reducing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the f-16.net link from Ron Beyer (and many personal years working on them by me), CCW as sitting in the seat. So CW looking from front to back.

**Why?**
You'd have to ask the designers. But one possibility might be that the rotation imparts a little bit of sideways momentum as the round leaves the barrel end. You'd want that sideways bit to be *away* from the aircraft body, not towards it.

Pure conjecture on my part, though.

Comment: hmmm, so you CAN curve the bullet...